Is it possible to change the thickness of brackets and fraction lines in an equation in Word 2024 for Mac?
I have converted the font in each equation into the same used in the content of my thesis (Garamond). However, the brackets and horizontal divider line in a fraction seem disproportionally thick compared to my equation's text now.
To convert the font of the equation's text into Garamond, I go into the 'Equation' tab and click 'font'. This, however, does not work for brackets and fraction lines. Is there a way to do something similar for these elements of my equations?
